# Getting a popup for downloading the font file(ttf) in a spring-boot application

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, fonts, spring-boot, mime-types

I'm getting a popup for downloading the fonts files(ttf) in a spring-boot application, the font file is related to bootstrap3.

[image]

I tried to add MimeTypes like this but still getting the popup for first time I open the application.

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.MimeMappings;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class ServletCustomizer implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        MimeMappings mappings = new MimeMappings(MimeMappings.DEFAULT);
        mappings.add("woff","application/x-font-woff");
        mappings.add("eot","application/vnd.ms-fontobject");
        mappings.add("ttf","application/x-font-ttf");
        container.setMimeMappings(mappings);
    }
}
```

I'm using Spring-boot 1.3.3.RELEASE+thymeleaf.
Anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the issue by adding this line to my security config

```
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/fonts/**").permitAll();
```